# Generate large(512 bit+) prime number python 3.6

Tags: rsa, primes, python-3.6

I've been attempting to generate large prime numbers with Python for RSA encryption for the past week and a half, with no luck. The Fermat primality test is infeasible at scales of 512 bits, and I can't quite wrap my head around Miller-Rabin. (I'm 13) All the scripts online seem to work with versions of Python below the one I'm using.  What should I do to generate massive primes? (Yes, probabilistic primes are fine.)

Comment: The fermat primality test should be perfectly feasible for numbers of the size you are interested in. Just make certain you use the 3-arg version of pow, e.g. `pow(2, p-1, p) == 1`

Answer (score 3):

Here is my Miller-Rabin prime checker:

```
def isPrime(n, k=5): # miller-rabin
    from random import randint
    if n < 2: return False
    for p in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]:
        if n % p == 0: return n == p
    s, d = 0, n-1
    while d % 2 == 0:
        s, d = s+1, d/2
    for i in range(k):
        x = pow(randint(2, n-1), d, n)
        if x == 1 or x == n-1: continue
        for r in range(1, s):
            x = (x * x) % n
            if x == 1: return False
            if x == n-1: break
        else: return False
    return True
```

If you want a guaranteed prime (not a probable prime), that's not very much harder to arrange. See [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/2017/03/31/generating-random-large-primes/) for a method due to Pocklington.

Comment: do you know the accuracy rate of your function?

Comment: It depends on the value of *k*. If you want less chance of error, use a larger *k*. But for 512-digit numbers, *k* is sufficient. If you're worried about the chance of error, use the method of Pocklington described on my blog, which is guaranteed to produce a prime.

Comment: We have to differ between testing for prime-ness with a probabilistic method, proving an arbitrary number for prime-ness and generating a proven prime of a given length.